# Call RelayCommand in another class MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using a RelayCommand  with delegate access in my project. it's a call with a behavior. When I used Directly in ViewModel it works fine.

but I would like to pass this command in a class in order to use it generically. the behavior still works but no sign of life of the command.

The command in my ViewModel(Work):

```
LoadCommand = new RelayCommand<object>( new Action<object>(
           obj =>
           {
               if (Busy)
                   return;

               Busy = true;
               System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                  delegate
                  {
                      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
                           delegate
                           {
                              // myReference.AddDatas(Mvts);
                              AddMoreItems();
                               Busy = false;
                           }));
                  });
           }));
```

And the command in my new class (doesn't work):

```
public Action<object> LoadCommand(Ref<ObservableCollection<T>> myList)
    {
        return new Action<object>(
         obj =>
         {
             if (Busy)
                 return;

             Busy = true;
             System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                delegate
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
                         delegate
                         {
                             AddDatas(myList);
                             Busy = false;
                         }));
                });
         }));
```

Call with

```
LoadCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(myReference.LoadCommand(Mvts));
```

All I know is that after putting breakpoints at the beginning of the order, it is not called.

For more informations my behavior call LoadCommand when scroll of datagrid is bottom

```
 public class ScrollViewerMonitor
{
    public static DependencyProperty AtEndCommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AtEndCommand", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ScrollViewerMonitor),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnAtEndCommandChanged));

    public static ICommand GetAtEndCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(AtEndCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAtEndCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AtEndCommandProperty, value);
    }


    public static void OnAtEndCommandChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
            element.Loaded += element_Loaded;
        }
    }

    static void element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);
        if (scrollViewer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(scrollViewer, delegate (object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                           >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
            if (atBottom)
            {
                var atEnd = GetAtEndCommand(element);
                if (atEnd != null)
                {
                    atEnd.Execute(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null)
                {
                    return typedChild;
                }
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

although it reached in both cases  **atEnd.Execute(null);**

But when command  execute in other file **the property below IsAlive = False**

[image: IsAlive = false]

and when command is directly execute in VM IsAlive is to True with my target object

[image: Isalive true]

Comment: Please provide some infos WHY it doesnt work. Also, have you tried to debug the new code and can give us a clue what to look for?

Comment: How do you call LoadComand(...) ? and how do you use the command, which LoadCommand(..) returns?

Comment: maybe you are calling `Command` from various instances or your `viewModels`? are you sure that this is the same instance your `viewModel`?

Comment: No i think is not the same instance when i try to return Action

Comment: Since it reached atEnd.Execute(null) in both cases, then can't you break at it then step into the code and see where it goes?

Comment: So you've answered to your question why your `Command` is not invoked.

Comment: Now yes, but keep alive my execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no chance to call `Command`, cause you are calling not the same instance of your `viewModel`.

To make some actions(for example, run your Command or edit some property)  in your `viewModel` from another `viewModel`, it is better to use `EventAggregator pattern`.

In my view, the best approach is using EventAggregator pattern of Prism framework. The Prism simplifies MVVM pattern. However, if you have not used Prism, you can use Rachel Lim's tutorial - [simplified version of EventAggregator pattern by Rachel Lim](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/). I highly recommend you Rachel Lim's approach.

If you use Rachel Lim's tutorial, then you should create a common class:

```
public static class EventSystem
{...Here Publish and Subscribe methods to event...}
```

And publish an event into your OptionViewModel:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeStockEvent>().Publish(
    new TickerSymbolSelectedMessage{ StockSymbol = “STOCK0” });
```

then you subscribe in *constructor* of another your MainViewModel to an event:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeStockEvent>().Subscribe(ShowNews);

public void ShowNews(TickerSymbolSelectedMessage msg)
{
   // Handle Event
}
```

The Rachel Lim's simplified approach is the best approach that I've ever seen. However, if you want to create a big application, then you should read [this article by Magnus Montin](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) and [at CSharpcorner with an example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ffb84/prism-event-aggregator-in-wpf-with-mvvm/).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I realized that there is more effectivemnt on the same instance and need to find a way around the problem by EventAggregator. However, this is beyond my skills and seems hard for me to implement it. Moreover, this solution could be used in a module out of the program? Because my program is well advanced implement Events aggregator would be an additional srucharge. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CamilleColvray yeah, you can use simplified version of `EventAggregator` pattern. Just follow Rachel Lim's tutorial. It is really simple. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/

Answer (score 1):

Those two are completely different, the first one is some kind of property which shows a proper Command binding and second one is a method returning RelayCommand. I dont think you can bind a Command property to a method. That might be reason why it doesnt work.

Comment: actually I tried but the result is the same in both cases.